# Inserting many records

Tags: c, database, sqlite

The output of the program generates random results for a 100 rounds of 100 coin tosses. I need to get all of those H & T results (10,000) into SQLite for analysis.

Round 1:
TTTTTHHTHTTHHTTTHHTTTTTTTHHTTHHHHHHTTTHTHTTHHTTTHHHHHHTHTTTTHTHHTHTTTHTHTHTHTTHHTTTTTTHTHTTHHTTTTHTH

-

Round 99:
TTHHHTHTHHTTTHHTTHTHTHTTHHHHHTHTTTTHHHHTHTHTHTHHHHTTTTTHTTHHHTTTTHTTHHHHTTTTTTHHTHTTHTTTTHTHHTTHHTHT

Round 100:
THTHTHHHHHTTHTTTTTTTTTTTHTTHHTHHHTHHTHHHHTTHTHHTTHTHTHHTTHHHTHTHHTHTTTTTHTHTTHHTHTHHHTHTHHTHTHHTTTHH

I have little knowledge how to do this, so I looked into what others have done. Apparently Multi-row INSERT is not supported. Some sources say the only way to insert several rows in a batch is use a Select statement. How would I achieve this?

Assuming the database and table is already created, what code could I use in a C program to insert all this data into SQLite?

```
/* This file was mechanically generated from tests/check-pcg32.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pcg_basic.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Read command-line options

    int rounds = 1000;
    bool nondeterministic_seed = false;
    int round, i;

    ++argv;
    --argc;
    if (argc > 0 && strcmp(argv[0], "-r") == 0) {
        nondeterministic_seed = true;
        ++argv;
        --argc;
    }
    if (argc > 0) {
        rounds = atoi(argv[0]);
    }

    // In this version of the code, we'll use a local rng, rather than the
    // global one.

    pcg32_random_t rng;

    // You should *always* seed the RNG.  The usual time to do it is the
    // point in time when you create RNG (typically at the beginning of the
    // program).
    //
    // pcg32_srandom_r takes two 64-bit constants (the initial state, and the
    // rng sequence selector; rngs with different sequence selectors will
    // *never* have random sequences that coincide, at all) - the code below
    // shows three possible ways to do so.

    if (nondeterministic_seed) {
        // Seed with external entropy -- the time and some program addresses
        // (which will actually be somewhat random on most modern systems).
        // A better solution, entropy_getbytes, using /dev/random, is provided
        // in the full library.

        pcg32_srandom_r(&rng, time(NULL) ^ (intptr_t)&printf, 
                  (intptr_t)&rounds);
    } else {
        // Seed with a fixed constant

        pcg32_srandom_r(&rng, 42u, 54u);
    }

    printf("pcg32_random_r:\n"
           "      -  result:      32-bit unsigned int (uint32_t)\n"
           "      -  period:      2^64   (* 2^63 streams)\n"
           "      -  state type:  pcg32_random_t (%zu bytes)\n"
           "      -  output func: XSH-RR\n"
           "\n",
           sizeof(pcg32_random_t));

    for (round = 1; round <= rounds; ++round) {
        printf("Round %d:\n", round);
        /* Make some 32-bit numbers */
        printf("  32bit:");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            printf(" 0x%08x", pcg32_random_r(&rng));
        printf("\n");

        /* Toss some coins */
        printf("  Coins: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            printf("%c", pcg32_boundedrand_r(&rng, 2) ? 'H' : 'T');
        printf("\n");

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are three files in all: pcg32-demo.c (the one with the code example here), pcg_basic.c and pcg_basic.h

Comment: All that code does is print out random numbers (and it's lifted from the pcg test suite). Where does sqlite come into play?

Comment: No, there will be no database nor tables (i.e. database schema) created automatically "on the fly".  You could do some of that beforehand using another tool, but you could also do it in code, but that is not answerable by anyone else since it is up to you to decide how you want to create and prepare the database.  Regardless of how you create and set up the database, you'll still need to include an sqlite library in the code, then add code to open the connection, then code to execute inserts into the database.  All that is too broad for a stack overflow question.

Comment: @Shawn. Because I will be analysing millions of records, I will first store the rounds in a SQLite database.

Comment: @C Perkins. Okay point taken. I will use a tool (DB Browser for SQLite) to create the database and tables ahead of time.

Comment: Include an SQLlite library in the code. This would be done by including this header file: #include <sqlite3.h> --- Is that correct?

Comment: @Stephan Schlecht --- What code would work for this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I would start with a simple approach and if you need to access results based on rounds and tosses, your table in the database could consist of three fields, e.g. `round`, `toss` and `result`.

To create the database and the table, you could use the command line program sqlite3 as follows:

```
sqlite3 random.sqlite
```

Then enter the following command at the command prompt:

```
CREATE TABLE experiment (round INT, toss INT, result CHAR(1));
```

Now you have created a database `random.sqlite` and a table `experiment`.

How to fill this table from C?

One way would be:

- open db
- create a prepared insert statement
- start a transaction
- in a loop:

  - bind values to parameters
  - run the SQL
  - reset prepared statement
- end transaction
- finalize the statement and close the db to avoid resource leaks

A simple example of the flow described could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

void exit_with_error(sqlite3 *db, const char * msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
}

char *pathToDB = "<a path to random.sqlite>";

sqlite3 *open_db(void);
sqlite3_stmt *prepeare_stmt(sqlite3 *db);
void close_db(sqlite3 *db, sqlite3_stmt *stmt);


int main() {
    sqlite3 *db = open_db();
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = prepeare_stmt(db);

    if(sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        exit_with_error(db, "begin transaction failed");
    }

    char *result = "H";
    for(int round = 0; round < 100; round++) {
        for(int toss = 0; toss < 100; toss++) {

            //for a short test simply output alternately "H" and "T"
            result = strcmp(result, "H") == 0 ? "T" : "H";

            //bind values to parameters
            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, round);
            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, toss);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, result, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

            //run the SQL
            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                exit_with_error(db, "insert failed");
            }

            //reset prepared statement to be able to bind new values in next loop pass
            if (sqlite3_reset(stmt) != SQLITE_OK) {
                exit_with_error(db, "reset failed");
            }

        }
    }

    if(sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        exit_with_error(db, "end transaction failed");
    }

    //finalize the stmt and close db to avoid resource leaks
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}

sqlite3 *open_db(void) {
    sqlite3 *db;

    if (sqlite3_open(pathToDB, &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        exit_with_error(db, "can't open db: ");
    }
    return db;
}

sqlite3_stmt *prepeare_stmt(sqlite3 *db) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    //create a prepared statement
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO experiment VALUES (?1,?2,?3)", -1, &stmt, 0);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        exit_with_error(db, "failure preparing insert");
    }

    return stmt;
}
```

Note: Instead of using random values, the code simply outputs 'T' and 'H' alternately to have a simple test case.

After executing the program, you can take a look at the stored values with the command line as follows:

```
sqlite3 random.sqlite
```

At the sqlite command prompt you can enter:

```
SELECT * FROM experiment;
```

The following should then be output in the console:

```
0|0|T
0|1|H
0|2|T
...
99|97|H
99|98|T
99|99|H
```

To get the value for the third toss in the first round you would issue the following sql statement from the command prompt:

```
SELECT * from experiment WHERE round=0 and toss=2;
```

that would output something like this on the console:

```
0|2|T
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have been at a roadblock with this. Even tried the C++ version.

Comment: Is it better to use code to create the SQLite db and table instead of doing it from the command line? The problem is: When I build the program in Xcode, it cannot find the db/table (path problem?). Output: failure preparing insert: no such table: experiment

Comment: most likely it's a path problem, on the terminal command line take a look where you create the random.sqlite db (e.g. /Users/mjm or something similar) - then in the line `char *pathToDB = "<a path to random.sqlite>";` replace `<a path to random.sqlite>` with an absolute path (e.g. `/Users/mjm/random.sqlite`) so that it looks like `char *pathToDB = "/Users/mjm/random.sqlite";`

Comment: Some progress but ”Build Failed"  

This is the absolute path, and what I used in the code:     
* char *pathToDB = "/Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoinToss1/Build/Products/Debug/random.sqlite";  
error message: Expected identifier or ‘('

Comment: Further down in the code another problem comes up (related to the first one?):    
 if (sqlite3_open(pathToDB, &db) != SQLITE_OK) {  
error message: Use of undeclared identifier 'pathToDB'

Comment: you should not use the path ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/... - it is managed by Xcode for intermediate build results and could also be cleaned in between. Use something like `/Users/Mike/random.sqlite` or `/Users/Mike/db/random.sqilte`.  The answer above compiles correctly, just copy it over once again and add the correct path to the db there - also follow the instructions in the answer to create the table and it will work ;-)

Comment: Build still fails for me...   * char *pathToDB = "Users/Mike/Development/db/random.sqlite";  error message: Expected identifier or '('

Comment: Using DB Browser for SQLite, I have checked, the db has been created correctly and so has the table. It looks good at that level. What is wrong with the path?

Comment: (1) there should be no `*` at the beginning of the line, so it is *not* `* char *pathToDB = "U...` -> instead the line should start with `char *...` - take a look at my answer
(2) an absolute path starts with `/` so it should be `char *pathToDB = "/Users/Mi...` and *not* `char *pathToDB = "Users/Mi` - perhaps take a look at the code sample and instructions again

Comment: Okay, that is working correctly now, it builds as it should, be there is the following error message:   can't open db: : unable to open database file
Program ended with exit code: 1

Comment: double check your path (you get this message typically if the path is not correct (e.g. if a subdirectory of the path is not created or wrongly spelled))

Comment: I can't see any fault with the path, spelling etc. I have renamed directories and created a new path, just to be sure, but the same result. Is there another possibility for this error? Thanks

Comment: How does the line starting with `char *pathToDB =` look like now in your code?

Comment: char *pathToDB = "Users/Mike/Development/Database/random.sqlite";

Comment: I think I (now) see the problem. It should be: char *pathToDB = "/Users/Mike/Development/Database/random.sqlite";  Is that correct? Was missing a forward slash.

Comment: Great news, the db is now populated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a round "0"? Instead of the first round being "1", it is tabled as "0". (BTW, would it be a good idea to close this question as it has been answered for the question asked? Perhaps db questions could be part of a separate thread?)

Comment: Yes it is correct you should use a forward slash as first parameter, see Point (2) in my comment above :-)  In C normally one works with indices starting from 0, so the first element usually has the index 0, but if you don't like this in the DB you can start from 1. And you are right, since this question seems to be answered, consider to accept it, for new questions, think about asking  new ones (the help center can be helpful, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking ).

Comment: Despite the fact that the original (Melissa O’Neil)l program provided true random distribution, I have noticed an anomaly with the revamped one.

Comment: Instead of there being some expected distribution of randomness (e.g. for 10 tosses, an outcome of 4 heads or 6 heads), each and every time it is exactly 0.50000 (exactly 50% heads). Even if I generate 1000 tosses, it will be exactly 500 heads every time. In fact, even the sequence looks suspicious: Tail - Head - Tail - Head all the way to the end without deviation. I have run all the tests again so as not to bother you with a false finding. But I think something is amiss. Unless I have screwed up somewhere... Do you mind taking a look when have a moment? Thanks, Stephan Schlecht

Comment: Of course this is the case. 

This answers your question, what code could be used in a C program to insert data into SQLite. In the answer I have the sentence: _Note: Instead of using random values, the code simply outputs 'T' and 'H' alternately to have a simple test case._

You just need to use _your_ own real data and insert it to Sqlite as shown.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood that was a literal implementation, because all along my mission was to get the random data generated from the actual Melissa O'Neil program into the database. Suggestions?

Comment: You have the Melissa O'Neil program that generates random data in two nested loops, and you have a working, complete, self-contained sample program that is capable of writing data from two nested loops into the database. Just combine both.

Comment: By the way: From your last comment one could conclude that you neither read the text of the answer nor took a look at the source code. If you have a programming problem, here on Stackoverflow are lot's of fine competent folks who volunteer to help if they can see that you have at least made a little effort to find a solution.

Comment: Actually I have spent many frustrating days trying to piece this altogether. As an absolute beginner, this has been beyond me, but I have stuck with it anyway. That's despite wanting to give up on it. I finally connected it up to SQLite and got all of that working only to discover that I had assumed wrongly about the code you provided. Not all is lost, I am just three-quarters of the way there instead of at the end point. And yes, there are a lot of good folks here, including yourself, that have generously helped. I can imagine it must be very frustrating for the helpers too.

Comment: No worries. In the beginning the learning curve is quite steep. Trying to achieve too complex goals right at the beginning leads to frustration. It often makes sense to start with simple exercises and then increase the difficulty level step by step.

Comment: Working on it ;)

Comment: The program now correctly inserts the random data into the database. I have run several tests and it appears to be correct as far as I can tell. That's good news. I don't know if I did it the best way (maybe there are better ways to do it?), but I am not too fussed about that. If you are curious, I will create a link to inspect the code. Thanks for your help on this.